# Run android app on Vmware host:windows 7 guest:android 4.4

Tags: android, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

How can I run android app on android 4.4 running in vmware. I've developed my application in windows 7

Comment: If you can access adb via TCP through the vm networking somehow, you can adb install it.  Otherwise send the apk as an email attachment or get it from a web page or install a file manager and click on it in a shared folder.

Comment: I don't know how you can run it in vmware - But, if it's because you don't like the emulator that comes along with the android SDK, you should tryout Genymotion: http://www.genymotion.com/ - It runs in VirtualBox, and is a very nice alternative to the standart emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Set vmware network adapter to NAT . Then start your android machine and after is initialized press

> ALT + F1

An interface like a cmd will apear . Type

> netcfg

and get the IP address showed there (not the one of localhost 127.0.0.1, the other) . Go into your windows 7 host and open command prompt. Type

> adb connect ip-address

Enter eclipse. Near run button is an arrow press it and select Run Configurations . Double click Android Application . In the target tab you can select Always prompt to pick device. Save settings and run your application. You are ready to go !